# regex - double quote to double-double quote escape in xml tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string and I want to replace all quotes (") with double quotes ("") using Regex Replace. I want to replace only those quotes that are between > and <
How do I do that?

Example:
Before

```
<Root>
    <Elem1>Hello "ds e"" 1293"</Elem1>
    <Elem2>sDieo " qqq "" dwe</Elem2>
</Root>
```

After

```
<Root>
    <Elem1>Hello ""ds e"""" 1293""</Elem1>
    <Elem2>sDieo "" qqq """" dwe</Elem2>
</Root>
```

NO STRING.REPLACE PLEASE, ONLY REGEX

Comment: No need for Regex.  Use : string output = input.Replace("\"", "\"\"");

Comment: I don't even know where to start. That's why I asked...

Comment: @jdweng It'll replace for any attributes in the xml as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for this and replace:

```
/"(?![^<]*?>)/g
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/vZ9vW0/1

EDIT:

Include regex to prevent matching except inside tags:

```
"(?=[^<>\n]*?<\/[^<>\n]*>)
```

Comment: It also matches first double quotes just before the first <. Do you know how to ignore those too?

Comment: As in <Root>"<Elem1> ?

Comment: I took a stab at excluding as much as possible outside tags. https://regex101.com/r/vZ9vW0/3 Be aware that this means it will not work for node content that isn't on the same line as the closing tag. It's the only way I can think of to prevent matching before tags. If you need that, you could try to remove either of the `\n` inside the character groups and see if you get what you need.